# Code mirror hint popover styling

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to change the HTML content being shown in code mirror hint box with different styles and content.Is there any API which does that?

Answer (score 0):

**Style**
You can use the [CodeMirror Theme API](https://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html) in order to do this using just CSS.  I would also take a look at some of the specific themes [here](https://github.com/FarhadG/code-mirror-themes).

**Content**
This would be a little more complicated.  Depending on your behavior, it is likely you would need to write [an addon.](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api)